# Issue with finding sum of the divisors of a number

Tags: python

```
def get_sum_of_divisors(number):
    div = 2
    total_sum = 1
    while div < number:
        if number % div == 0:
            total_sum = total_sum + 1
        div = div + 1

    return total_sum

def main():
    print("get_sum_of_divisors(24)", get_sum_of_divisors(24))
    
main()
```

I am trying to create a program which find the sum of the divisors of a number (excluding the divisor which is the number itself). I have checked the code multiple times but my code seems to return the value '7' for the divisors of 24, even though it should be 32.

Is there something wrong with the indentation? Does the div = div + 1 need to be somewhere else along the line?

Comment: Why are you adding `1` to the `total_sum`? You should be adding the `div` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace this line,
total_sum = total_sum + 1
with this,
total_sum = total_sum + div